# jQuery Accordion Content then Fade In

Tags: jquery

I have a UL with a bunch of LI's.  Now, when I click on an LI I do an Ajax call and get a SPAN returned to me.

What I'd like to do is move the LI under the clicked one down and then fade in the new SPAN in the hole produced by moving the LI down.

I'm kinda not allowed to use an accordion in this instance if it can at all be helped.

Does anyone know how to do this or how to get the height of content returned from an ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").click(function() {

  // do your ajax call, success function:
  success: function(data) {
    $(this).after(
      $(data).hide().fadeIn(500)
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: I think this is what you want, isn't it?